# How to remove the screensaver password on OS X with apple script or shell?

Tags: macos, applescript

I want to write a little apple script that disables my screensaver password whenever my phone is in range with Bluetooth. I have spent quite a bit of time search and I have not been able to actually find anything that works.  I have tried things like:

```
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.screensaver askForPassword -int 1
```

But, this does not seem to be working on OS X 10.6.  Does anybody know how to do this on OS X 10.6 (preferably in apple script or from the shell)?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is not the expected answer: [There is already an App for it](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/).